# Black line header ios 7

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, ios7

I'm trying to adapt my iOS 6 app to the new iOS 7 and I have found a problem that I can't fix.
As you can see in the images, it appears a black line in the header image. I think that this black line is because the background image is duplicated and the black line is just the end of the image and where starts the other.

[pic 1 http://d3j5vwomefv46c.cloudfront.net/photos/large/810043729.png?1379670640](http://d3j5vwomefv46c.cloudfront.net/photos/large/810043729.png?1379670640)
[pic 2 http://d3j5vwomefv46c.cloudfront.net/photos/large/810043923.png?1379670706](http://d3j5vwomefv46c.cloudfront.net/photos/large/810043923.png?1379670706)

The white one is a white image background

What I have done right now is to put the edges to none:

```
 if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)]) {
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
}
```

**EDIT**:
If I comment the line where I assign the image to the background, I can't se the black line! There all white, obviously without the image "forex crunch". **So now, the question is, how can I put a background image in the navigation bar in iOS7?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have read in the Apple developers forum is to create an image with 64px instead of 44px. That's the solution for this problem

Answer (score 0):

Only thing to do is set ShadowImage with this code and black line is off.

> ```
> [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"navBarBack"]
>                                               forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
> [self.navigationController.navigationBar setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
> ```

In this case I put navBarBack.png as navigationBar background. This image has 640pxx96px.